# How do I solve this IE7 margin issue?

Tags: html, css

I have put a margin bottom for inputboxes. In Firefox4, the spacing between the inputboxes and the .link seems fine but using IE7, the spacing seems to double.. How can I fix this?

HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link type="text/css" href="css/Exam.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
<!-- start wrapper -->
<div class="wrapper">

    <!-- start header -->
    <div class="header">
        <div class="Login">
           <h1>User Login</h1>
           <form name="Login" method="#" action="#">
                <input type="text" value="User Name" />
                <input type="password" value="password" />
           </form>
           <div class="links"><div>Not yet a Member?</div> <a href="" class="Register">&nbsp;Register Now</a> <a href="" class="btn_login"><span>Login</span></a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End header -->

    <!-- Start main -->
    <div class="main"></div>
    <!-- End main -->

    <!-- start footer -->
    <div class="footer"></div>
    <!-- End footer -->

</div>
<!-- End wrapper -->
</body>
</html>
```

CSS File :

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

/*  CSS Reset  */
ul,li,h1,h2,h3{padding:0;margin:0;}
ul{list-style:none;}

/*  CSS for wrapper  */
.wrapper{background:#fffde4  ;width:601px;margin:0 auto;border:#000 thin groove;color:#bb9d59;padding:17px 28px 28px 35px;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }

/* Header */
.header{width:601px;overflow:hidden;}
 .Login{width:390px;float:right;}
h1{margin-bottom:7px;color:#2c787b;font-size:27px;}

input[type="text"],input[type="password"]{width:172px;height:21px;color:#bb9d59;background-color:#f9f6d4;border:none;font-size:10px;padding-left:9px;float:left;line-height:21px;margin-    bottom:14px;}
input[type="password"]{margin-left:25px;}
.links a,.links a:link{color:#943415;text-decoration:none;float:left}
.links{clear:both;border:#000 thin groove;overflow:hidden;}
.links div{float:left;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eb2zR/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Apply `overflow: hidden` to the `form`.
- Move the `margin` on the `input`s inside `form` to `form` itself.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/eb2zR/1/